# Emulate Network address in a LAN

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, subnet, proxy-server

My college has a network, their dhcp will allot us a xx.xx.67.xx ip (Wifi), i found that in their lab they use a different proxy that is restricted for our ip range(Squid) (xx.xx.1.xx is their ip range). when i am manually configure my network interface to their ip range it doesn't ping to the both proxy, but in default dhcp i can ping both.

Is there any emulators that can emulate my ip address to their range of ip ? so that i can fool squid ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Along with setting the IP, can you also make sure that you set your DNS and Defaulot Gateway correctly?

Comment: i have set default gateway same as in the lab, i don't think dns will matter when we know the IP .

Comment: I am using windows, network adapter displays a domain in Network adapter when it is in default range and undefined network when in their ip range.

Comment: Does the network in the Lab connected via the same SSID as you are connecting? If not then the SSID you are using is configured to use a different IP range but you are trying to force your PC to talk to that network using a different network IP. Since that SSID network does not recognize your IP, it discards your packets.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an address from network A in network B without network A cooperating. This is by design:

1. It keeps the routing tables manageable
2. It provides *some* security

So, unless you have a cooperating machine in network A (willfully or not), there is no way to get this to work.

Actually, the easiest way is to have the administrator of the squid proxy enter you into the access list. Better yet: Have them switch to a account-based access (personal login+password), unless they want to grant access the entire WiFi network. (They might also generally try to think about which services to offer to whom, based on what criteria.)